# how to pass pointer to a function?

Tags: c, pointers

I am writing a function to find a value in a hash table. Why is there a run time error each it reaches line 6? Please Help!

```
int* value = 0;
printf ("find return value: %d \n", find(keyList[i], value));
```

The above two lines are the function calls used in main.

```
int find( char *key, int *p_ans ){
int hashValue = hash(key);
entry* newTable = table[hashValue];
while (newTable != NULL){
    if ((newTable -> key) == key){
        *p_ans = newTable -> val; // THE ERROR LINE
        return 1;
    }
    newTable = newTable -> next;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you pass in as `p_ans`?

Comment: How are you calling this function?

Comment: Hint: crank up compiler warnings, and fix warnings so you get warning free code. This will catch a lot of bugs, possibly also you calling this function with somehow bad p_ans...

Comment: You're **explicitly dereferencing a null pointer.** If you don't see this, you should probably be still learning the basics of C **much better** instead of already writing this and that.

Comment: @H2CO3 Posting to SO is a way to learn.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Yes. But not in the case of this kind of questions.

Answer (score 3):

Because `p_ans == NULL`. Change your call to one of these:

#### Stack

```
int value;

if (find(keyList[i], &value)) {
    printf ("find return value: %d\n", value);
}
else {
    printf ("not found\n");   
}
```

#### Heap

```
int *value = malloc(sizeof(int));

if (find(keyList[i], value)) {
    printf ("find return value: %d\n", *value);
}
else {
    printf ("not found\n");   
}

free(value);
```

The point is that you need to have a space allocated for an integer. If you have a local variable `int value` then you can pass its address and `find` will change the variable's value.

If you have `int *value` then you've got a pointer. This pointer needs to point to an int somewhere. `malloc` allocates space for an `int` value.

Writing `int *value = 0` doesn't create an int with a value of 0, it creates an int *pointer* with a value of NULL (0 means NULL when used as a pointer value). You can't dereference this NULL pointers. If you call `find(keyList[i], NULL)` then `p_ans == NULL`, and `*p_ans` dereferences a NULL pointer and crashes your program.

If it still doesn't make sense, consider these two code snippets. The first one will crash. The second one will work. Do you see why?

```
// Bad
int *pointer = NULL;
if (find(keyList[i], pointer))

// Good
int value;
int *pointer = &value;
if (find(keyList[i], pointer))
```

Comment: Probably. Or an uninitialized pointer.

Comment: it works, but why cant i do int *value;
printf ("find return value: %d \n", find(keyList[i], value));

Answer (score 3):

You need to allocate the `int` outside the function; either on the stack or on the heap.
To allocate it on the stack, just do

```
int ans;
find(key, &ans);
```

To allocate it on the heap, do

```
int* p_ans = new int;
find(key, p_ans);
...
delete p_ans;
```

Comment: why? Isnt ans a pointer? the why do why use the address of a pointer?

Comment: My code declares `ans` to be an integer. The address of `ans` (i.e., a pointer) is passed to `find`. In `find`, the name of this address is `p_ans`.

Comment: Yep, it is working. but why cant i do int *value; printf ("find return value: %d \n", find(keyList[i], value));

Comment: @user1745626: Because the pointer is again not pointing to an `int` that was allocated somewhere. See my edit for how to allocate on the heap.

Answer (score 3):

You are setting this:

```
*p_ans = newTable -> val; // THE ERROR LINE
```

for this you have to malloc, at p_ans, but your p_ans pointer is 0, which is obtained from 'value' variable, which points to 0, that is the issue

add this line:

```
value = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int));
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because you pass a pointer to `NULL`. You don't have to actually declare a pointer to pass a pointer to a function, instead use the address-of operator `&`:

```
int value = 0;
printf ("find return value: %d \n", find(keyList[i], &value));
/* Using address-of operator here -------------------^ */
```

Comment: How about  int *value = 0; printf ("find return value: %d \n", find(keyList[i], value)); This is not working either.

Comment: @user1745626 No that won't work because you are declaring a _pointer_ an making it point to `NULL`, which is an illegal address to access (in most cases). Either do as I said in my answer, declaring a _normal_ and _non-pointer_ variable and use the address-of operator (which returns a pointer) or allocate memory on the heap with e.g. `malloc`.